Release Pipeline Started Failing (TLS / Certificate Issue)
A few days ago, a couple of our Azure release pipelines began to fail.
The pipelines deploy to our client's self-hosted machines - both a test and production environment; neither pipelines are working anymore. We haven't changed anything in the pipeline and the client says nothing has changed in their infrastructure (taking this with a grain of salt, as we have a bunch of our own self-hosted machines where the deployments are still going through).
The error is occurring in the deployment group job when it attempts to do the artifact download. This is what the log output looks like:

2024-04-24T01:28:35.4107721Z Error: in getBuildApi, so retrying =>
retries pending : 4
2024-04-24T01:29:20.5325958Z Error: in getBuildApi, so retrying =>
retries pending : 3
2024-04-24T01:31:35.6424623Z Error: in getBuildApi, so retrying =>
retries pending : 2
2024-04-24T01:37:35.7312572Z Error: in getBuildApi, so retrying =>
retries pending : 1
2024-04-24T01:43:35.9335199Z ##[error]Failed in getBuildApi with
error: Error: unable to verify the first certificate at
TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1674:34) at TLSSocket.emit
(node:events:518:28) at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:1085:8)
at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:871:12) { code:
'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' }
2024-04-24T01:43:36.0200040Z ##[error]Error: unable to verify the
first certificate

So far we've tried:

Installing all Windows updates on the target machines.
Removing and reinstalling the Azure Agent onto the target machines with a new token.
Ran the TLS checker and applied mitigations. https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-tls12
Set the environment variable NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 on the test environment to see if it'd go through. It does, but we can't leave it like this.
Got the client to check that none of the URLs here are being blocked by their firewall

Any ideas on how we can fix this or further narrow down the problem? We're a bit puzzled as to why we're suddenly getting a bad certificate.

It could be caused by the ESET antivirus on the agent machine, please check the similar ticket shared below. thanks.

As per the same error in similar ticket, it could be caused by the ESET Antivirus which blocks the node call.
An easy solution is to tell nodejs to use the system CA cert… store by running:
node --use-openssl-ca
Or add an exception for Node in SSL protection rules:


This was indeed the issue. Looks like another ESET update also went through today, which may have corrected the issue (I didn't have to do node --use-openssl-ca in order to get it working).
